# How do I select the value of the last row of a specific column of each dataframe in a list using a for loop?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes with the same variables but varying number of observations. For example, the last 10 rows of one of my dataframes are as follows:

```
BIN_END_TIME  AVERAGE_PUPIL_SIZE_BIN
3238          172
3258          171       
3278          171
3298          170
3318          170
3338          169
3358          169
3378          169
3398          170
3409          169
```

What I hope to achieve is extracting the last value of the **BIN_END_TIME** variable (e.g., 3409) of each of the dataframes in the list using a for loop.

May I know if anyone knows a way to do so? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `sapply`. If your list of dataframes is called `list_df` :

```
result <- sapply(list_df, function(x) tail(x$BIN_END_TIME, 1))
#Also : 
#result <- sapply(list_df, function(x) x$BIN_END_TIME[nrow(x)])
```

---

With a `for` loop :

```
result <- numeric(length(list_df))

for(i in seq_along(list_df)) {
  result[i] <- tail(list_df[[i]]$BIN_END_TIME, 1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! May I know how to do it using a for loop?

Comment: omg thanks so much! if it's not too much trouble may I know if you know a way around this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337813/how-to-add-mutiple-geom-vline-using-values-derived-from-the-last-value-of-the-x/67338584?noredirect=1#comment119032011_67338584. I'm stuck and I can't seem to get my question reopened...

Comment: Okay thanks for the reminder! Sorry I'm pretty new here...

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply`

```
result <- unlist(lapply(list_df, function(x) tail(x$BIN_END_TIME, 1)))
```